# Which index varies fastest in a VB array?

Tags: vb6

When using a Visual Basic two-dimensional array, which index varies fastest? In other words, when filling in an array, should I write...

```
For i = 1 To 30
    For j = 1 To 30
        myarray (i,j) = something
    Next
Next
```

or

```
For i = 1 To 30
    For j = 1 To 30
        myarray (j, i) = something
    Next
Next
```

(or alternatively does it make very much difference)?

Comment: With values higher than 30, this is definitely something that you should be able to measure (and if you can't, well, you have answered your last question).

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen. I haven't used Visual Basic for about a year, and have an interview tomorrow where I will be asked questions on it. I don't have a VB Studio at home, and was trying to prepare for some likely questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Column major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). VB6 [uses COM SAFEARRAYs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263528(v=VS.60).aspx) and [lays them out in column-major order](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207931). The fastest access is like this (although it won't matter if you only have 30x30 elements).

```
For i = 1 To 30 
    For j = 1 To 30 
        myarray (j, i) = something 
    Next 
Next
```

If you *really* want to speed up your array processing, consider the tips in [Advanced Visual Basic by Matt Curland](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201707128), which shows you how to poke around inside the underlying SAFEARRAY structures.

For instance accessing a 2D SAFEARRAY is considerably slower than accessing a 1D SAFEARRAY, so in order to set all array entries to the same value it is quicker to bypass VB6's SAFEARRAY descriptor and temporarily make one of your own. Page 33.

You should also consider turning on "[Remove array bounds checks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716334(v=VS.60).aspx)" in the project properties compile options.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if (or where) this is specified. It might be left as 'implementation defined'.

But I would expect the first index to be the 'lower' dimension, ie the big chunks, and the following index positions to be ever more fine-grained.

**Edit:** Seems I was wrong. VB6 uses a Column-first approach.

> Does it make much difference?

You would have to measure but using the <strike>lower</strike> higher dimension for the outer loop would allow the compiler to generate faster code and could make better use of the processor cache (locality). But with a size=30 I wouldn't expect much difference.

Comment: Actually VB6 uses COM SAFEARRAYs which are laid out the other way: column major.

Comment: @MarkJ: OK, thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit a little.